# Quadrature encoder reading 2500pps 10000rpm

Tags: filter, noise, encoder

I am using a Quadrature encoder 2500ppr @ 10000rpm → 416666.66 pps. When reading these pulses using a microcontroller, so far I found medium filters are used before the micro controller to remove noises. How do I design a proper medium filter for this type of encoder?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your questions shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far in detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: *"How design a proper medium filter for this type of encoder?"* depending on what you are trying to filter out. generally the onboard electronics does a pretty good job so additional signal conditioning isn't required.

Comment: The OPs numbers do tally. It looks like 166 rps or 10000RPM and 2500 ppr so 166x2500=415000 pps (with some rounding error hiding in there).  This is a high quadrature rate to handle in a uC without good interrupt code, dedicated hardware or low processor loading.

Comment: @KalleMP If I use an FPGA what are things I should consider? I am considering use of 50MHz clock to run IPs.

Comment: This is not my speciality but my first step would be to see how others have done it, Google is your friend.  An FPGA would be a handy solution given your input rate, it sounds like a lot of encoder lines for that speed, usually you do not have any way to control something that fast and accurate, could it be over specified?  What is the Application?  A dedicated servo control IC may be the least design cost here if you are trying to control a motor.  An FPGA should cope fine if you are just monitoring.

Comment: @KalleMP replying What is the Application? to measure engine speed of course.

Comment: @vassidefuk, how often do you need to know, two pulses are enough to get a reasonable estimate? Why have a quadrature signals are you uncertain of the direction of rotation?  This does not compute.

Comment: @KalleMP using quadrature encoder 2500 ppr I count 10000 pulses per round using its offset. Because of that both channels are used.using inverted channel I do the same direction is not required.

Comment: @vassidefuk, how often do you need to know, two pulses are enough to get a reasonable estimate?  How accurately do you need to know?  (Shakes head some more)

Comment: @KalleMP basically the rpm value will be read continuously when ever engine runs  i dont get what you meant by **how often do you need to know**

Comment: This is not a link only comment  -  http://www.instructables.com/id/RPM-Measurement-Using-Hall-Sensor-and-Arduino/

Comment: "to measure engine speed of course... I do the same direction" - so you just want to measure rpm and don't care about direction? Then just count the pulses in a timer with prescaler. The prescaler will automatically filter out noise as it divides the pulse rate down to a lower frequency.